# Form submitting duplicate comments to mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a comment section to my pages which stores the comments in a mysql database. However when I click send, it sends duplicates of the same comment into the database. I can't see where I may have sent the query twice however.

```
<?php
            if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) { 
                $name = strip_tags($_POST['name']);
                $message = strip_tags($_POST['message']);
                $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $name);
                $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $message);

                $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM comments";
                 $result = $db->query($query);
                 $data = $result->fetch_assoc();


                 $query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`work_id`, `sender_ name`, `message`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$message."')"; //id comes from a $_GET at the top of the page
                 $db->query($query);
                 $result = $db->query($query);

                 $query = "INSERT INTO `comment_work` (`comment_id`,`work_id`) SELECT `comments`.`id`, `comments`.`work_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`sender_ name` = '".$name."' AND `comments`.`message` = '".$message."'";
                 $db->query($query);
                    $result = $db->query($query);




            if ($result) {
              echo "<p>Comment submitted!</p>";
            } else {
                echo "SQL Error: " . $db->error;
            }
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: I'm not putting in an answer here; but you're querying twice.

Comment: I forgot to thank you as well!! You're a star!

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`work_id`, `sender_ name`, `message`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$message."')"; //id comes from a $_GET at the top of the page
$db->query($query);//one query - **YOU must remove this line!**
$result = $db->query($query);//second query
```

To

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`work_id`, `sender_ name`, `message`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$message."')"; //id comes from a $_GET at the top of the page
$result = $db->query($query);
```

And here

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comment_work` (`comment_id`,`work_id`) SELECT `comments`.`id`, `comments`.`work_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`sender_ name` = '".$name."' AND `comments`.`message` = '".$message."'";
 $result = $db->query($query);
```

Comment: I'm embarrassed at how I didn't catch that.. thank you for replying!!

Answer (score 1):

Cause is simple:

Look at these code lines:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`work_id`, `sender_ name`, `message`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$message."')"; //id comes from a $_GET at the top of the page
                 $db->query($query);
                 $result = $db->query($query);

                 $query = "INSERT INTO `comment_work` (`comment_id`,`work_id`) SELECT `comments`.`id`, `comments`.`work_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`sender_ name` = '".$name."' AND `comments`.`message` = '".$message."'";
                 $db->query($query);
                    $result = $db->query($query);
```

Well, here you are executing a query with `$db->query` and then with `$result = $db->query` you executing another time the same query.

Replace this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comment_work` (`comment_id`,`work_id`) SELECT `comments`.`id`, `comments`.`work_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`sender_ name` = '".$name."' AND `comments`.`message` = '".$message."'";
$db->query($query);
$result = $db->query($query);
```

With:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comment_work` (`comment_id`,`work_id`) SELECT `comments`.`id`, `comments`.`work_id` FROM `comments` WHERE `comments`.`sender_ name` = '".$name."' AND `comments`.`message` = '".$message."'";
$result = $db->query($query);
```

And this:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`work_id`, `sender_ name`, `message`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$message."')"; //id comes from a $_GET at the top of the page
$db->query($query);
$result = $db->query($query);
```

With:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `comments` (`work_id`, `sender_ name`, `message`) VALUES ('".$id."','".$name."','".$message."')"; //id comes from a $_GET at the top of the page
$result = $db->query($query);
```

So should work.